# Where are all database file paths stored in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Where are the paths for all the database files stored in SQL? eg: paths for mdf,ldf files for TempDB, and other databases.

I need to find out the file that contains all the paths. I have by mistake changed the TempDB path and I am not able to login into SQL to change it. I need to restore the SQL to previous working state. So I need to know which file to replace inorder to get the correct paths back.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Use [your Database Name]
    SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_helpfile Databasename

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use sys.master_files.

Answer (score 0):

you can access them through the sql management studio (the database properties)
do you ask where does it gets the info from ? it's probably in one of the system tables.

[image]